# asynctask WAIT mode

Tags: android-asynctask, wait, kill

When i press button1 (execute) on UI i run AsyncTask. The task was run success.

[image: Run first time task]

I press another button2 (cancel) to stop asynctask from main thread

```
asynctask.cancel(true);
```

but AsyncTask thread dont self kill! (see second screenshot)
The asynctask switch to WAIT mode

[image: task in wait mode]

then i can press button1 (execute) again and run NEW task and press button2 (cancel)

[image]

And i have queations:

Why task dont selfkill after used cancel(true)?
And whay mean WAIT mode?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask under the hood uses a ThreadPoolExecutor. Those threads might not go away for a bit because it'd be a waste to keep creating and tearing down those threads too often. After a while if you create more AsyncTasks you'll find that it'll stop creating new threads and it'll re-use the old ones.

Update to address some details:

You would think that if there are free threads in the pool, it wouldn't create new ones, but this isn't exactly true. The idea is that there's a certain number of threads that are useful to have around to keep processing asynchronous tasks. This is called the core pool size. In Android's AsyncTask case, they seem to have set it to 5. If you look at the documentation for ThreadPoolExecutor it says:

```
When a new task is submitted in method execute(Runnable), and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle.
```

There's also a maximum fittingly called the maximum pool size.